# Symfony: error general instead of close of concerned input (fos username)

Tags: forms, symfony

Good morning,
I have extend my bundle of FOS and create a form for subrscription, everything works well exept that errors concerning userName are not linked to the field, they are at the top of form.
I have only use simple annotation like * @Assert\NotBlank().
It works perfect email whitch link correctly errors but not for $username.
Thank of your help.

```
   namespace ***\UserFosBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use ***\UserFosBundle\Form\Type\InfosPersonFormType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class RegistrationFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder

           ->add('userName', 'text', array('label' => 'form.username', 'translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle'))
           // ->add('firstName', 'text', array('label' => 'form.firstName', 'translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle'))
            ->add('email', 'email', array('translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle'))

            ->add('plainPassword', 'repeated', array(
                'type' => 'password',
                'options' => array('translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle'),
                'first_options' => array('label' => 'form.password'),
                'second_options' => array('label' => 'form.password_confirmation'),
                'invalid_message' => 'fos_user.password.mismatch',
            ))

        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'OSF\UserFosBundle\Entity\User',
            'validation_groups' => array('Default', 'Registration')
        ));
    }

    // BC for SF < 2.7
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $this->configureOptions($resolver);
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'fos_user_registration';
    }
}
```

and the entity

```
<?php

namespace ***\UserFosBundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * User
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="users")
 * @UniqueEntity("username")
 * @UniqueEntity("email")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    protected $facebookId;

    /**
     * le login pour la connexion
     * @var string
     * 
     * @Assert\Length(min = "2", max = "255", minMessage = "form.error.atLeast", maxMessage = "form.error.noMore")  
     */
    protected $username;


    /**
     * @var string
     * @Assert\NotNull()
     * @Assert\Email(message = "form.error.email", checkMX = true)
     */
    protected $email;

    /**
     * Plain password. Used for model validation. Must not be persisted.
     *
     * @var string
     * @Assert\NotNull()
     * @Assert\Regex(pattern="/[A-Z]/", message="form.error.maj")
     * @Assert\Regex(pattern="/[0-9]/", message="form.error.number")
     * @Assert\Length(min = "7", max = "255", minMessage = "form.error.atLeastOnenumber", maxMessage = "form.error.noMore")  
     */
    protected $plainPassword;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="OSFAPI\Bundle\NotificationBundle\Entity\Notification", mappedBy="user")
     */
    protected $notifications;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="OSFAPI\Bundle\NotificationBundle\Entity\Device", mappedBy="user")
     */
    protected $devices;

    /**
     * [$person description]
     * @var [type]
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="OSF\PersonBundle\Entity\Person", mappedBy="userfos")
     */
    protected $person;
    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->notification = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
        $this->devices = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
        $this->mobilenotifications = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();

    }
```

Comment: Add code snippets from your code.

Comment: ok done, but i think it is more a problem from FOS than of my code

Comment: Have you tried using `username` instead of `userName` (in the name of the form field)?

Comment: ho, you re a god man I don't understand how my code was working with this fault it seems Symfony is demis case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

riska was right I just need to lowercase the 'N'.